# Iteration through data structures(queue, stacks, bags)

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, queue

```
Queue<Transaction> collection = new Queue<Transaction>
```

and

```
for(Transaction t: collection)
{ StdOut.println(t); }
```

From my understanding of objects, it looks like we just created an object, the queue, of datatype transaction(type parameter) and collection is the reference to that object. Correct?

Then the second bit of code is what confuses me. We are looping to print whats in the queue but i'm not sure i understand how this works. collection points to the Queue of type Transaction. It looks like we are creating a reference t to the object Transaction and doing something with it to the reference collection. Pretty confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html. Queue is part of the Java Collection Framework and therefore implements the Iterable interface. The for-each shortcut uses that fact and utilise the Iterator object that Queue produces to iterate over all elements.
It's equivalent to:

```
Iterator<Transaction> I = collection.iterator();
for(;;I.hasNext()) {
  Transaction t = I.next();
  StdOut.println(t);
}
```

Comment: I think this explained it the best

Answer (score 2):

This is syntactic sugar that java has for dealing with iterators. Queue implements the `Iterable` interface. The for loop asks for the `collection`'s iterator and knows how to handle it.

For each class that implements `Iterable` you can use this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The "for-each" notation is actually replaced by this in the final class file:

```
for(Iterator i = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); Transaction t = iterator.next())
```

This just obtains an iterator and sets `t` equal to the next value of the iterator each time through the loop. This can be done with any object that implements `Iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that the `Queue` has an `iterator()` method. When you feed it to a `foreach-loop` like you are doing here, you are calling an iterator-object. Next the for-loop starts iterating through the objects in that iterator.

Answer (score 0):

For `for(Transaction t: collection)` read:

*For each Transaction in collection*

or

*For Transaction t over collection*.